# Graying out texts with/without lines with LaTeX?

Tags: latex

This is a screen capture from Pragmatic Bookshelf.

[image]

How to make this boxed text with LaTeX? It has it's own heading with underline, and uses color.

And how to make some  text with gray background as follows?

http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/7351/screenshot20100718at916.png

#### Added

Konrad's method works, but it looks like that it doesn't work well with multicolumn package.

Tonio's method shows the gray only for the characters, but I want to have the gray box expanded to the end of \textwidth.

http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/8417/screenshot20100718at247.png

I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277197/textwidth-for-multicolumn-document-in-latex) with respect to the \texwidth, and it seems to working anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rounded box is most easily created using [**Tik*Z***](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!20,rounded corners,inner sep=2ex,text width=\textwidth] {
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \dots
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: width=\textwidth doesn't seem to work with multicolumn environment.

Comment: @prosseek: there seem to be several quirks with boxes of fixed width … I’m no expert of TikZ myself, and I have a lot of trouble getting some of the things to work … but try `0.5\textwidth`.

Comment: @prosseek: the following worked for me: use [`\newlength`](http://www.eeng.dcu.ie/local-docs/latex-help/ltx-87.html) to define a new length (let’s call it `\halflength`), set that length to `0.5\textwidth`, add to that `-0.5\columnsep` (using `\setlength` and `\addtolength`, respectively) and use the resulting `\halflength` as the text width.

Comment: It simply amazes me that this answer has got a downvote. Come on people … seriously?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`color`](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/latex_advanced/node13.html) package.

For example,

```
\colorbox{red}{Black text on red background}
```

creates a black text, with a red background.
A good description of the `color` capabilities can be seen [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/computing/latex/color.html), and an extended example [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/color-package.html).

Comment: And the rounded box can be obtained using a technique similar to the one used [here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/07/wrapping-text-in-rounded-corners-colorbox-in-latex-with-tikz-and-pgf/), with [tikz/pgf](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

Comment: Is there a way to make \colorbox expand to the end of \textwidth?

Comment: You can simply put your text in a `parbox` of length `\textwidth`, with `\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\textwidth}{Black text on red background}}`