# How to make the grayed-round box using tiks

Tags: latex, tikz

This is a follow-up question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275851/graying-out-texts-with-without-lines-with-latex). I need to make a round-grayed box as is shown.

[image]

Based on the answers, I tried something, but not so fruitful. So, another questions coming.

I came up with the following command, but it doesn't work. The verbatim inside the minipage doesn't compile.

```
\newcommand{\graybox}[1]{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,inner sep=2ex,text width=\mytikzwidth] {%
  #1
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

%% ERROR - verbatim doesn't work. 
\graybox{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\mytikzwidth}
...
\begin{verbatim}
java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script \$1
\end{verbatim}
...
\end{minipage}
}
```

I also tried with the environment, which also doesn't work. The minipage isn't sit inside the minipage.

```
\newenvironment{grayboxx}%
{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,inner
  sep=2ex,text width=\mytikzwidth] {%
}%
{};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

**Questions**

- What's wrong with the LaTeX code? How can I use verbatim environment with minipage in the tikzpicture?
- Could you teach me a better way to implement the grayboxed environment as is shown in the attached picture?

This is the whole code, and I attached the compiled result with the compiled result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\mytikzwidth}
\setlength{\mytikzwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\mytikzwidth}{-4ex} % this 10ex is just rule of thumb.

\newcommand{\graybox}[1]{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,inner sep=2ex,text width=\mytikzwidth] {%
  #1
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newenvironment{grayboxx}%
{\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,inner
  sep=2ex,text width=\mytikzwidth] {%
}%
{};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

%%%% CASE 1 - OK
\begin{minipage}[b]{\mytikzwidth}
clj command is as follows.

\begin{verbatim}
java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script \$1
\end{verbatim}

hello.clj needs a namespace (ns) to let the modules know about this code.
\end{minipage}

%%%% CASE 2 - not working with verbatim
\graybox{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\mytikzwidth}
clj command is as follows.

%\begin{verbatim}
java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script \$1
%\end{verbatim}

hello.clj needs a namespace (ns) to let the modules know about this code.
\end{minipage}
}

%%%% CASE 3 - not inside the tikz
\begin{grayboxx}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\mytikzwidth}
clj command is as follows.

%\begin{verbatim}
java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script \$1
%\end{verbatim}

hello.clj needs a namespace (ns) to let the modules know about this code.
\end{minipage}
\end{grayboxx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the same question to [LaTeX Community](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9665), and I got the following answer from Juanjo.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\RoundedBoxWidth}
\newsavebox{\GrayRoundedBox}
\newenvironment{GrayBox}[1][\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5ex]%
   {\setlength{\RoundedBoxWidth}{\dimexpr#1}
    \begin{lrbox}{\GrayRoundedBox}
       \begin{minipage}{\RoundedBoxWidth}}%
   {   \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
       \draw node[draw=black,fill=black!10,rounded corners,%
             inner sep=2ex,text width=\RoundedBoxWidth]%
             {\usebox{\GrayRoundedBox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{GrayBox}
  clj command is as follows.
  \begin{verbatim}
  java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script \$1
  \end{verbatim}
  hello.clj needs a namespace (ns) to let the modules 
  know about this code.
\end{GrayBox}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{GrayBox}[0.75\textwidth]
  clj command is as follows.
  \begin{verbatim}
  java -cp \$CLOJUREJAR:\$CLASSPATH 
  clojure.lang.Script \$1
  \end{verbatim}
  hello.clj needs a namespace (ns) to let the modules 
  know about this code.
\end{GrayBox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```